# C++ object reference

Tags: c++, object

I have this piece of code:

```
Wmmbid02 wmmbid02;
wmmbid02.Omplir(this);
return wmmbid02;
```

and Wmmbid02.h:

```
class Wmmbid02: public Idoc {

public:
    Wmmbid02();
    //void EscriureFitxer();
    void Omplir(Edi);

private:
    Segment crearSegment(string a[], string b[]);
    Info crearInfo(string);
    //virtual void LlegirFormat(string);
};
```

Visual Studio, returns and error because can't convert 'Edi *const ' to 'Edi'.

What is the correct answer???

Thanks

Comment: Pass an `Edi` instead of a `Edi*`...

Comment: `wmmbid02.Omplir(*this)` will clear the error, but maybe that's not exactly what you want.

Comment: `*this` instead of `this` for a start.

Comment: maybe it's me, but the names are very dutchy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration of `Omplir`

```
void Omplir(Edi);
```

says that this method take an `Edi` object.

In C++ `this` is a pointer. You should use it inside a class.

If you want it to work, you should dereference it:

```
wmmbid02.Omplir(*this);
```

---

The standard says about the `this` pointer:

> **9.3.2 The this pointer [class.this]**
>
> In the body of a non-static (9.3) member function, the keyword this is a prvalue expression whose value is the address of the object for which the function is called. **The type of this in a member function of a class X is X*. If the member function is declared const, the type of this is const X***, **[...]**

So in your case, you seem to be in a member function of the class `Edi`, `this` should be of the type `Edi*`.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the definition for `this` I'd say you'll probably want to replace `void Omplir(Edi);` by `void Omplir(Edi* const);` and adapt the definition of `Omplir` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Either define the parameter `void Omplir(Edi)` to a pointer:

```
void Omplir(Edi*);
```

Or pass `this` as reference:

```
Wmmbid02 wmmbid02;
wmmbid02.Omplir( *this );
return wmmbid02;
```

But it really depends on what you exactly want to do. Usually i prefer passing by references whenever possible.